# ¿Cómo convertir letras con acentos?

Tags: python, string

tengo una duda, debo realizar un ejercicio en el cuál debo determinar si un string es palíndromo, el tema es que debo tener en cuenta las letras con acento, intenté modificarlas manualmente pero no lo estoy pudiendo realizar.
Mi código es este:

```
def capicua(string):
    cadena=string.lower()
    cadenavacia=""
    for letra in cadena:
        if letra=="á":
            letra="a"
        else:
            if letra=="é":
                letra="e"
            else:
                if letra=="í":
                    letra="i"
                else:
                    if letra=="ó":
                        letra="o"
                    else:
                        if letra=="ú":
                            letra="u"
    for i in range(len(cadena)):
        if cadena==cadena[::-1]:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    


print(capicua("hola"))
```

Comment: Te recuerdo, te dejé un comentario diciendo que uses elifs. Si lees esto, te recomiendo dar atención a los comentarios. Pueden traer consejos.

Comment: Lo siento, muchas gracias, comenzaré a usarlos.

Comment: No problem. Lo dije más por ayudarte. No estoy ofendido c: